# Toggling active class on buttons in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to toggle the active class in a button group on ReactJs. I followed an example posted by somebody but cannot seem to get it to work. Below is my code:

```
class ButtonGroup extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {
        active: this.props.active || 0
      };
    }

    clickHandler(e) {
      var nodes = Array.prototype.slice.call( e.currentTarget.children );
      var index = nodes.indexOf( e.target );
      e.preventDefault();
      this.setState({ active: index });
    }

    render() {

      var buttons = this.children.map(function(child, i) {
        if (i === this.state.active) child.props.className += ' active';
        return child;
      }, this)

      return (
        <div className="ButtonGroup" onClick={this.clickHandler.bind(this)}>
            { buttons }
        </div>
      )
    }
}

class Nav extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <ButtonGroup>
        <a onClick={Link.handleClick} href="/profile" className="MenuLink active">Profile</a>
        <a onClick={Link.handleClick} href="/profile/works" className="MenuLink">Works</a>
        <a onClick={Link.handleClick} href="/profile/activity" className="MenuLink">Activity</a>
        <a onClick={Link.handleClick} href="/profile/following" className="MenuLink">Following <span className="FollowCount">{this.props.following}</span></a>
        <a onClick={Link.handleClick} href="/profile/followers" className="MenuLink">Followers <span className="FollowCount">{this.props.followers}</span></a>
      </ButtonGroup>
    );
  }
}
```

The error I am getting:

```
Unhandled promise rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'active' of undefined(…)
```

React Version: 0.14-rc1

Would really appreciate if my error is pointed out and for a solution to this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Which line is the error thrown? Make sure `this` is correctly set.

Comment: It is hard to figure out which line it is referring to. It is showing: es6.promise.js:108

Comment: Open your browser's developer tools and enable "break on exception" (and also breaking on caught exception if necessary).

Comment: Now getting "Unhandled promise rejection TypeError: this.props is undefined" so it must be the line 6

Comment: I haven't used the newer react with es6 classes but try looking into that constructor, ``this.props`` may not yet be available

Answer (score 0):

First off, `this.children` should be `this.props.children`. (***Note***, if you're passing children dynamically you need to remember that passing just 1 child will not yield an Array as when passing multiple children and therefore `this.props.children.map()` will not work.)

Secondly, `this.props` and succinctly `this.context` won't be populated in the constructor of the class ***unless*** you're passing the `props` to both `constructor` and `super`. Therefore either passing them or moving it out of the constructor entirely are the ways to go.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            active: this.props.active || 0
        }
    }
}
```

Thirdly, without knowing what `Link.handleClick` is, your code should work if you fix the above things.

And lastly, just as a matter of taste and preference, instead of littering your code with `this.someMethodOnMyReactComponent.bind(this)` you could bind it straight up when defining the method.

```
someMethodOnMyReactComponent = (args) => {}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, like you mentioned the part this.props.children.map() does not work. I am getting "TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'className' of [object Object]". I tried using 'classnames' on the buttons and assigning 'active' to a variable with the name 'status' on each button's classnames, but then I get "TypeError: Can't add property status, object is not extensible". Any idea of a solution for this? Thanks